# FTP client that functions similarly to Dropbox?

Tags: ftp, synchronization, dropbox, file-sharing

I'm trying to help a wonderful designer who is sadly running out of space on her Dropbox, but is already paying for hosting service that has 100GB available for her. Is there a software that works and that is seamlessly integrated within explorer and updates files on FTP that you yourself can assign?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborarate on the 100GB storage, she already has? What are the bindings? How can you access that space? Or are the 100GB already used up and you need more space.

Comment: It's a virtual hosting with FTP access, she just doesn't want to use a separate client, like FileZilla, when using it. Well technically she would use a separate client, but she'd like it seamlessly integrated to operating system folders, such as with Dropbox.

Comment: similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/416040/dropbox-like-client-for-ftp WinSCP and Git-Ammex are both great alternatives. But I believe there's still nothing as simple as

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like FTPBox http://ftpbox.org/

Comment: Yes, I actually found that since. It was not available at the time of question :)

Comment: @kristovaher neither seem good enough (for mac and pc), since it's windows only

Comment: True. She's using Google Drive now (as am I, actually), since we get 100GB for $5 a month, much cheaper than Dropbox. I edited the question to remove Mac from being mentioned, since answer is otherwise not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hell in your case Id consider buying a NAS drive :)
QNAS make about the best on the market, they can be rigged up as ftp servers, have almost a terabyte space, allow for windows and linux integration and make brilliant samba servers.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, though, since it isn't software-only and couldn't use the space she already has.

Comment: It does offer a better alternative and can the data can be copied to the nas drive so Im not so sure that it deserves a mark down..

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your requirements, which you have not stated too clearly.
Do you want Internet storage (web/dav/ftp/sftp) or storage within your own network?

If you are looking for a solution which is available for almost every OS and where the storage is located somewhere in our wonderful Internet-verse, **webdav/s** could be the solution.
I'm not really sure, if I understand the statement "files on FTP that you yourself can assign".
Please be a little bit more specific.

Comment: Sorry if I was not specific enough. She has a virtual hosting with FTP access, which she would like to access on her PC at home and Mac at work. She wants the software to work similarly to Dropbox (www.dropbox.com), right within operating system explorer and folders, synchronizing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Why not Filezilla?

http://filezilla-project.org/

Comment: If you are looking for a cross-platform ftp/s client, Filezilla is definitely the way to go...

Comment: Sorry if I was not specific enough. She has a virtual hosting with FTP access, which she would like to access on her PC at home and Mac at work. She wants the software to work similarly to Dropbox (www.dropbox.com), right within operating system explorer and folders, synchronizing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try IQBox, my own free open-source project. It syncs using FTP-SSL by default (you can use non-SSL FTP also, but not recommended due to security.) It's a simple sync app for FTP.
[Official Download Page for IQBox FTP Client](https://www.iqstorage.com/iqbox.php)

[Google Code Project Page](http://code.google.com/p/iqbox-ftp/)

Answer (score 0):

If they are using Windows they can set up an FTP account as a "Network Location", then you can use it like a regular folder on your PC. Drag and drop away.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/work-with-files-ftp-site#1TC=windows-7